# How to deny Embedded user agents accessing Authorization Server

Tags: iis, server, authorization, identityserver4, fido

I am using authorization code flow with PKCE, and would like to deny access to Authorization Server if the client is using an embedded user agent. I am using IdentityServer 4 for authorization server, and Asp.net core 2.2 for the API, both running on IIS 8.

I have search for solutions on how to deny embedded user agents on native application to access Authorization server, but I cant find any steps on how to implement/configure this. Is there anyone that could provide steps on how to deny access from these kind of applications?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Really the only thing to have to go on is the `User-Agent` header and that can easily be spoofed. I understand that using such an approach is not best practice but what is the problem you're trying to solve by blocking them?

Comment: I want to deny embedded user agents because It is unsafe for third parties including the auth server itself. Our customer is using Power BI desktop, and I am actually not sure if it is really necessary for this case. But in general desktop application is considered as a native application, and according to RFC 8252 (8.12) I should deny native applications from using embedded user agent, so I would like to follow this advice for this client. I also loose some SSO benefits and state if embedded user agent is used.

Comment: @mackie [rfc8252](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8252#section-8.12): _embedded user-agents violate the principle of least privilege by having access to more powerful credentials than they need, potentially increasing the attack surface._ And from [auth0](https://auth0.com/blog/oauth-2-best-practices-for-native-apps/#OAuth-2-0-Security-Considerations-for-Native-Apps): _Authorization servers may detect and block requests from embedded user agents, as they are unsafe for third parties, such as the authorization server itself._

Comment: From [auth0](https://auth0.com/blog/oauth-2-best-practices-for-native-apps/#OAuth-2-0-Security-Considerations-for-Native-Apps): _Authorization servers can protect against these fake agents by requiring an authentication factor only available to genuine external user agents._

Comment: That last point is interesting - requiring WebAuthn/FIDO2 authentication (possibly as a second factor) would probably achieve this goal. Not trivial but absolutely possible (I've done it recently). That would likely filter out all old implementations and also guard against the client being able to use intercepted values to sign in since the private key is protected user confirmation is required to complete an authentication request.

Comment: Yes @RuardvanElburg , I want to achieve; "require an authentication factor only available to genuine external user agents". But how is this configured/implemented step by step? Any code/configuraion examples would be appreciated here.

Comment: You may find [this thread](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/179756/why-are-developers-using-embedded-user-agents-for-3rd-party-auth-what-are-the-a) interesting. From one answer: _I want to add that [U2F](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71316/how-secure-are-the-fido-u2f-tokens/71704#71704) makes authentication from the browser nearly unphishable_.

Comment: U2F is effectively obsolete now that FIDO2 is a thing and is available in (nearly) all browsers but the same basic principles apply. For a .Net server implementation check out https://github.com/abergs/fido2-net-lib.

Comment: Thanks mackie and RuardvanElburg, I will have a look into those links

Comment: @RuardvanElburg.Yes, I will post an answer if I find any solution that will work.

Comment: I don't know if you got any further, but here's a [link](https://deblokt.com/2019/10/21/08-identityserver4-mfa-fido2-yubikey-5/) that shows IdentityServer4 MFA – FIDO2 (YubiKey 5).

Comment: @RuardvanElburg, Thanks. Unfortunately, I have not had time to dig further into this. But will look at this when I get the time :)