# Multiple Logins on one machine - ASP.NET Core Identity & Identity Server 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have Identity Server 4 running locally with the Quickstart UI from their Quickstart tutorials.

I am trying to determine if I can have a dual login on the one machine, meaning as long as some condition is met, there could be two users logged in at the same time.

My Google searches seems to yield various posts that want to disable multiple logins, but when I tried logging in with first the `Bob` test user, and then secondly the `Alice` test user, I only had the one Identity cookie that Indeed was the `Alice` user.

So it appears out of the box, ASP.NET Core Identity/Identity Server is not allowing multiple users to be signed in at the same time.

I was hoping someone will be able to point me in a particular direction with this.

Comment: If you insist on having multiple logins on one machine, use a different browser for each user. That way you'll have seperate sessions.

Comment: Yes I've just found a post where I was indeed reading comments by yourself where someone was asking a similar question.  I have just tested Identity Server with Chrome and Firefox and it does login both users.  My next problem is working out how to allow and disallow this behavior with particular users.  I was thinking of extending the Identity user and having a flag to state whether they can login to a machine that someone else is logged into (in another browser of course).

Comment: How are you planning to determine if the browsers run on the same machine?

Comment: I'm not sure, do you mean that is the main challenge when trying to achieve something like this?

Comment: When the user is redirected to the login page of IdentityServer it cannot even tell the difference between a normal browser and an embedded browser, let alone if it runs on the same machine. For some more information on this read the question and comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59138227/how-to-deny-embedded-user-agents-accessing-authorization-server).

Comment: Thanks for the initial insight into this, I'll have a read.